Question about PKCE error when building app with expo
Just using expo to build an app which needs to connect with Epic, I'm using expo-auth-session as the auth library and here's the code:
import {
  useAuthRequest,
  CodeChallengeMethod,
  makeRedirectUri,
} from "expo-auth-session" 
const { codeChallenge, codeVerifier } = pkceChallenge();

  const [ , , promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      usePKCE: true,
      responseType: "code",
      clientId: epicClientId,
      redirectUri,
      scopes: ['fhirUser'],
      codeChallengeMethod: CodeChallengeMethod.S256,
      codeChallenge: codeChallenge,
      extraParams: {
        aud: 'my FHIR R4 URL'
      }
    },
    {
      authorizationEndpoint: 'authorizationEndpoint from epic',
      tokenEndpoint: "tokenEndpoint from epic",
    }
  );

But always get the error like
{"authentication": null, "error": [Error: The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.
More info: PKCE required for unsecured redirects], "errorCode": null, "params": {"error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "PKCE required for unsecured redirects", "state": "6Tul1Tw6mW"}, "type": "error", "url": "exp://192.168.1.9:8081/?error=invalid_request&error_description=PKCE+required+for+unsecured+redirects&state=6Tul1Tw6mW"}

I know expo is using url like exp://192.168.1.9:8081 locally, but I think I have set codeChallengeMethod and codeChallenge correctly, also set exp://192.168.1.9:8081 as redirectURI in server's redirectURI list, so really dont know what's the problem, anyone has clues?

Seems like the PKCE policy are different between each servers, some medical departments may use strict policy that dont allow any custom url like myapp://main, I just pop up a webview to do the whole OAuth process at last, then monitor the url and get the code I want, just want to remind other that dont waste time on this
